# Laravel - two factories refer to each other

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, factory

I have an existing database, what is not modifiable. My current job is to make factories.

In the present case I have two tables. One is the `item` table, and the other is the `item_image` table.

An item has many images, but the featured-image-id stored in the item.

Here is my two factories:

Item factory

```
$factory->define(Item::class, function (Faker $faker) {
   return [
    'title' => $faker->words(3, true)
    'user' => function () {
      return factory(User::class)->create()->id;
    },
    'featured_image' => function () {
      return factory(Image::class)->create()->id;
    },
  ];
});
```

ItemImage factory

```
$factory->define(Image::class, function (Faker $faker) {
  return [
    'item' => function () {
      return factory(Item::class)->create()->id;
    },
  ];
});
```

`item.featured_image` column:

- FK -> item_image.id
- Not NULL

`item_image.item` column:

- FK -> item.id
- Not NULL

For example, when I want to create an item, the item factory refers to the itemImage factory, which would create an item that would create an image. bla bla bla. It cause an infinity loop.

How should i rewrite these factories?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is caused by poor database design. If an image belongs to an item, then an item shouldn't also belong to an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to define factories in the way you want..

I'd keep it as you defined but use in the way so you don't create extra records like:

```
$item = factory(Item::class)->create();
$image = $item->image; // instead of factory(Image::class)->create(); since record is created
```

or

```
$image = factory(Image::class)->create();
$item = $image->item;
```